# How to Display Content of Multiple FIles Given in command Line argument in C

Tags: c

So I am trying to print the content of files which are given as an argument and the problem i am facing is when multiple arguments are passed it display the content of first file only.
Like if i give Input as `a.txt` `b.txt` `c.txt` it displays the output of `a.txt` and ends
the code i have written so far is:

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main(int argc,char*argv[])

    {

        if(argc<3)
        {
            printf("Insufficent Arguments");
            exit(0);
        }
        int i;
        FILE *fp;
        char c;
        for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
        {

            fp=fopen(argv[i],"r");
            if (fp == NULL )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "could not open file named %s!\n",argv[i] );
                return 2;
            }
            else
            {
            while (c != EOF) 
            { 
                printf ("%c", c); 
                c = fgetc(fp); 
            } 
            }
            fclose( fp );
        }

    }
```

This code is after all possible modifications i have tried to resolve the problem
Please can anyone guide me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What value does `c` have when first testing it?

Comment: You need `int c;`

Comment: Yes it has started Working Thank You i missed this minute detail will keep in mind this little things from next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first loop, you need to reset `c`. If you don't it keeps the last value from the previous file.

Also `c` **needs** to be `int`.

pseudo code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        c = 0;
        while (c != EOF) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it has started Working Thank You i missed this minute detail will keep in mind this little things from next time

Answer (score 0):

You may want to re-initialize your char 'c', that is used to check EOF. 
After first iteration/file, it ends up with EOF and since this char is declared outside it retains its value across files. So for other file it will never go inside while loop.

option 1: Move your **char c;** declaration inside else

Or

option 2: re-initialize your c before while, ***c = fgetc(fp);*** (yes, you will have to restructure print)